# Why does ObservableCollection<T> implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

In .NET 4.0, there isn't a single property defined by `ObservableCollection<T>` nor does it override any property of its parent or interfaces. So why does `ObservableCollection<T>` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

One reason I can think of is that it makes it easier for subclasses to define their own properties and use the `OnPropertyChanged` method implemented by `ObservableCollection<T>`. But is this the main reason?

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` has 3 properties, `Item` (the indexer), `Count`, and `Items`.

Comment: And while the indexer and items may not generate property change notifications, I wouldn't be surprised if Count did.

Comment: @JonSkeet looks like Indexer and Count do, but not Items. see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,4eb38b95b10327e7,reference source

Comment: @RonBeyer: Yup - just found that through testing myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but it looks to me that those three properties are inherited from `Collection<T>` and are not overridden by `ObservableCollection<T>` to raise a `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: @redcurry: Just because the properties themselves are inherited doesn't mean that the causes of them changing can't raise the events. See my answer for proof that they *do* raise the event.

Comment: @redcurry, take a look at the source I provided, it clearly shows that even though the properties are inherited, the events are handled by the `ObservableCollection` class.

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you all. I looked at the source code and clearly the event is being raised by other methods that cause those properties to change.

Comment: Note that of `Item`, `Count` and `Items`, only `Item` has a setter. `ObservableCollection` doesn't need to override `Count` or `Items` because they will only get change via other methods (like `Add` and `Remove`) and in the code for *those* methods, the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event will be triggered.

Comment: Also note, from @RonBeyer link to the source, the protected method `SetItem`, note the comments `Called by base class Collection<T> when an item is set in list;`, so that takes care of `Item` so `ObservableCollection` does not need to override `Item` either.

Comment: @MattBurland, I was just looking at that because I wanted to know how `ObservableCollection<T>` raises the `PropertyChanged` event when an item is changed via the indexer (since it is defined in `Collection<T>`, which does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`). The indexer actually calls `SetItem` in `Collection<T>`, which is overridden by `ObservableCollection<T>` and can therefore raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the properties `Item`, `Items` and `Count`, only `Item` actually has a setter, so there is no need to override `Items` or `Count` since you can't set them, there is no need to raise an event from it. They only change in response to some other method (like `Add` or `Remove`) and *those* methods will raise the necessary property changed events (actually if you look at the source, `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't override those methods either, but instead overrides `protected` methods that are called by `Add` and `Remove` in the base class).

Now for `Item`, the property isn't overriden, but if you look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,4eb38b95b10327e7) for the `SetItem` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Called by base class Collection&lt;T&gt; when an item is set in list;
/// raises a CollectionChanged event to any listeners.
/// </summary>
protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
{
    CheckReentrancy();
    T originalItem = this[index];
    base.SetItem(index, item);

    OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, originalItem, item, index);
}
```

You'll note from the comment that this is called by the base class when an `Item` is set and you'll also note that it fires off the `OnPropertyChanged` event.

If you look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,281923b8611114ec) for `Collection<T>` you can confirm that this is the case:

```
    public T this[int index] {
#if !FEATURE_CORECLR
        [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
#endif
        get { return items[index]; }
        set {
            if( items.IsReadOnly) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource.NotSupported_ReadOnlyCollection);
            }

            if (index < 0 || index >= items.Count) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            SetItem(index, value);
        }
    }
```

So in summary, `Item` in `Collection<T>` calls `SetItem` that is overridden in `ObservableCollection<T>` which triggers the `PropertyChanged` event.

Answer (score 3):

Both `Count` and `Item[]` changes are notified. Here's a sample (using C# 6 just for the string interpolation):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)collection).PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  {e.PropertyName} changed");
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Adding");
        collection.Add("Item");
        Console.WriteLine("Adding");
        collection.Add("Other item");
        Console.WriteLine("Removing");
        collection.RemoveAt(0);
        Console.WriteLine("Changing");
        collection[0] = "Different";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Adding
  Count changed
  Item[] changed
Adding
  Count changed
  Item[] changed
Removing
  Count changed
  Item[] changed
Changing
  Item[] changed
```

Comment: Guess you may want to say that this is a C#6 example :)

Comment: @RonBeyer: Was considering doing so, but I don't know how long that'll be relevant... will add a small note.