# Counter on generic list change C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, counter, observablecollection

I've been trying to work out a way to do something that seems so simple yet I'm getting nowhere with it. I just want to increment a counter every time I update a property in the list, but I don't want to write ChangeCount++; inside every If statement that results in a change, I want it to be in the data class and be more automatic.

I've tried writing a Set method in the DataClass, but that didn't work well, as I needed to pass it three parameters, it stopped me from using += and it was just as bad as writing ChangeCount++;. I looked at get; set; and although the count went up correctly if I added the auto increment to get, it always came out 0 when in the set. I looked at ObservableCollection using INotifyPropertyChanged, but it seems overly complicated for what I want to do, although I do feel this might the the only option, however I don't understand it enough to make it work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class DataClass
{
    public int ChangeCount { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public class Item
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

}

public class ProgramClass
{
    public static void doStuff()
    {
        var dc = new DataClass();

        dc.items = new List<Item>();    
        //List gets populated with lots of items...

        //loop list items with lots of if statements leading to possible
        //changes which should trigger the counter to increase.
        //e.g. 
        dc.items[i].someProperty += 10;

        //Now I want:
        If (dc.ChangeCount > 0) BackupOriginalFileAndWriteNewFile();
    }
}
```

Update: I just stumbled across [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342435/1703848) which appears to do exactly what I want, although I'm still interested to see other suggestions.

```
((INotifyPropertyChanged)dc.items).PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName != "Count")
        dc.ChangeCount++;
};
```

OK it's still not working. If I just change the values on the item and put it back in, it doesn't count as a change, it has to be a completely different item put in.

Comment: Why not just use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - That won't help to count changes on the properties of elements within the collection. It only helps with changing the elements themselves.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes that's what I've just realised, It works when I change the whole object, but not when I change a property of an object. How would you tackle it?

Comment: @dt192 - IMplementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is probably the most idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: If you don't care about performance or intellisense, there's probably a solution which uses `dynamic` and `DynamicObject`/`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` to wrap your object and keep track of properties/counts. That may be a bit extreme though and obviously has the downsides I've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Mb something like this:

```
public class DataClass
{
    public int ChangeCount => items.Sum(i => i.ItemChangeCount);
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }

    public class Item
    {
        public int ItemChangeCount { get; private set; } = 0;

        private int _prop1;
        public int Prop1
        {
            get => _prop1;
            set { _prop1 = value; ItemChangeCount++; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this and it does work, so many thanks for that. However it means adding an extra temporary variable plus the get; set; code for all 33 properties. Is there a way to set these in a loop? or have you got any other ideas? Thanks once again.

Comment: @dt192 Not so much a code solution, but if this idiom is going to be common enough for you and you don't want to keep repeating yourself, take a look at Fody. You may be able to set something up where you apply an attribute to your class/properties and Fody rewrites it into your change counter logic. They have a NotifyPropertyChange "weaver" that you may be able to leverage.